# Node.js: POST is not sending data to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to POST data using **Postman**. I am using **x-www-form-urlencoded** to post the data in **Local**.

There is showing no error.

After putting the data on postman, getting only the following data on Database:

```
{
    "createdAt": "2019-10-13T12:25:52.313Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-10-13T12:25:52.313Z",
    "_id": "5da317e0e5a3df0a90308f68",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Don't get reason behind not receiving the data in database. Any help would be appreciated.

routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Contact = require('../controllers/CrmController');

router.post('/create', Contact.addNewContact );
```

controller:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ContactSchema } = require('../models/CrmModel');

const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema, 'contact');

exports.addNewContact = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let newContact = new Contact(req.body);
        let contact    = await newContact.save();

        res.send(contact);

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }

    next();
};
```

model:

```
// Include MongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// To Remove Deprication Warning from Console
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

//Define a Schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema for The Current Model 
exports.ContactSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type : String
    },
    lastName: {
        type : String,
    },
    email: {
        type : String,
    },
    company: {
        type : String,
    },
    phone: {
        type : Number,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type    : Date,
        required: true,
        default : Date.now()
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type    : Date,
        required: true,
        default : Date.now()
    },
});
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const crmRoutes = require('./server/routes/crmRoutes');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Hello from Node App!');
});

app.use('/api/contact', crmRoutes);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/crmdb', (err) => {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('MongoDB has connected successfully!');
    } else {
        console.log('The error: ' + err);
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(3000, (err) => {console.log("Server Has Started");});

module.export = app;
```

Comment: can you share your request body as well??

Comment: @uvishere Solved: just by adding the routes after bodyParser middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the bodyParser middleware after you add your route. That means only routes added later will have it. You need to move the route after the middleware.

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot. I was wasting hours behind that :(

Comment: No problem! Please click to accept the answer. Thanks.